# Sample space and conditional probability?

Tags: probability

I'm so confused with how we're supposed to define sample space of a conditional event. It makes no sense to me.

My raw understanding of a sample space is: A set of outcomes from a experiment.

Event is a subset of that sample space.

And now introduces the definition of conditional event(or worse conditional probability).

Consider this problem:

The probability of a flawed product in a company is 10%. We have a machine that can detect a product's quality. The probablity of this machine detecting a flawd product is 85%. About that of a fine product is 5%.

What is exactly 85% or 5% percent here. It's so confusing.

Let us define sample space to explain the 10% part: The set of all products that are considered as flawed **by people**.

Now, 10% means the probability of event E: choosing a random product and you've accidentally picked a flawed one. E is set of all flawed products - satisfying the definition of an event.

But then what is 85%. The event "products that are considered flawed by machine" makes no sense. Yes, its some subset of sample space but which part? A product considered flawed by a machine isn't a real thing because we don't know the output!

How do you determine sample space here? That's my question. Thank you for reading?

Comment: I don't understand the confusion.  You have a bunch of units.  Some are defective, some aren't.  The defective ones form a subset, as do the non-defective ones.  You are told that if you give this machine a defective unit, it will (correctly) find the flaw $85\%$ of the time.  If you give the machine a non-defective unit it will (incorrectly) report a flaw $5\%$ of the time.  Is that clearer?

Comment: *"The probability of this machine detecting a flawed product is 85%. About that of a fine product is 5%"* indeed does not make much sense.  It would be more meaningful if it said that for flawed products it correctly says that they are flawed about $85\%$ of the times they are tested, and that for fine products, it incorrectly says that they are flawed about $5\%$ of the times that they are tested.

Comment: So,i guess here we have two sample space, right?

Comment: Now find the probability that the product is incorrectly detected :D. What's the sample space now? @Henry

Comment: Why are you upset that there are more than one sample spaces?  Isn't that normal?  If you are looking at a human population, you might want to restrict to males or to females, or to people with cancer, or to people under $5$ years old, and so on.

Comment: Here, we have to imagine that there is a well defined notion of "flawed" which the machine is a good, but imperfect, measure of.  You are just asked to analyze the ways in which the machine error might manifest itself.